# loading multiple entries into sql table using Golang

Tags: mysql, go

```
for _,data := range Array { 
    stmt, err := db.Prepare(INSERT log SET a=?,b=?,c=?)
    checkErr(err)
    _, err = stmt.Exec(data.a,data.b,data.c)
    checkErr(err)
}
```

This is the loop to add data into the table but the Go loop iterates faster than mysql can load entries into the table thus only the last few entries are populated, is there any way to load all the sql statements and populate the table at once?

Comment: `Go loop iterates faster than mysql can load entries` Oh, really?

Comment: Maybe you just have few entries in you array? Did you print it to see its' contents?

Comment: I have about 30,000 entries in the array, all of them have values I have printed them

Comment: `checkErr` shows you something?

Comment: `db.Prepare` should be outside the loop. The point is, prepare once, assign parameter many times.

Comment: nope checkErr doesn't raise any issue, I want want to know if there is a way  of loading the entire array into the table instead of looping though it and losing entries.

Comment: Thank putting the Prepare outside the loop fixed the problem